# Floodfill Not working (c)

Tags: c, flood-fill

I am having some trouble with my floodfill function not working.
The purpose of this assignment is to see if P and C are connected within the array.
In the floodfill function it doesnt seem to be changing the '_' to 'P'

Sample input

```
5 
1 2
PC
2 1
P
C
2 2
P#
#C
2 2
P_
C_
8 7
__P____
####_##
_____#_
_____#C
##_###_
_____#_
___#_#_
___#___
5 7
__P____
####_##
_____#_
_____#C
##_###_
```

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXC 10
#define MAXR 10

void floodfill(char map[][MAXC+1], int i, int j, int r, int c);
int checklocation(char map[][MAXC+1], int i, int j, int r, int c);

int main() {


    FILE* ifp = fopen("bunnies.in", "r");

    int numcases, loop;
    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &numcases);


    for (loop=0; loop<numcases; loop++) {

        int r, c, i=0, j=0;


        fscanf(ifp, "%d%d", &r, &c);
        //printf("\nRows = %d Cols = %d\n", r,c); //debug comment out
        char map[r][c];

        //Read in input
        for(i=0; i<r; i++) {

            map[i][j] = fgetc(ifp);

                for (j=0; j<c; j++) {
                    map[i][j] = fgetc(ifp);
                    //printf("%c", map[i][j]); //test input read comment out
                }
           // printf("\n"); //test input read comment out
        }

        int broken = 0; //to keep track if floodfill already occured

        for (i=0; i<r; i++) {

           // if (broken == 1)
            //    continue;

            for (j=0; j<c; j++) {

               // if (broken == 1)
                //    continue;

                //the whole loop only looks for P then floodfills
                if(map[i][j] == 'P') {
                    floodfill(map, i, j, r, c);
                 //   broken = 1;


                }

               // printf("%c", map[i][j]); //test floodfill, comment out later

            }

            //printf("\n"); //test floodfill, comment out later

        }

        int found = 0;

        //searches for C, calls checklocation when found
        for (i=0; i<r; i++) {
            for(j=0; j<c; j++) {
                if (map[i][j] == 'C')
                    found = checklocation(map, i,j, r, c);
            }
        }

        if (found == 1)
            printf("yes\n");
        else
            printf("no\n");

    }

fclose(ifp);
return 0;

}


//Pass map pointer, position in array i,j and row/column numbers
void floodfill(char map[][MAXC+1], int i, int j, int r, int c) {

//printf("looking at: [%d][%d]\n", i,j); //debug comment out later

//'base case' that deals with out of bounds
if (i<0 || j<0 || i>=r || j>=c)
    return;

if (map[i][j] != '_')
    return;

if (map[i][j] == '_')
    map[i][j] = 'P';



floodfill(map, r, c, i, j+1); //check right
floodfill(map, r, c, i, j-1); //check left
floodfill(map, r, c, i+1, j); //check below
floodfill(map, r, c, i-1, j); //check above

//printf("%c", map[i][j]);

}

//Same parameters as floodfill
int checklocation(char map[][MAXC+1], int i, int j, int r, int c) {

//these if statements check for p in each location around and
//makes sure the coordinate is in bounds
if (map[i-1][j] == 'P' && ((i>=0 && i < r) && (j>=0 && j < c)))
    return 1;

else if (map[i+1][j] == 'P' && ((i>=0 && i < r) && (j>=0 && j < c)))
    return 1;

else if (map[i][j+1] == 'P' && ((i>=0 && i < r) && (j>=0 && j < c)))
    return 1;

else if (map[i][j-1] == 'P' && ((i>=0 && i < r) && (j>=0 && j < c)))
    return 1;

else
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You'll learn much more if you figure out what's going on yourself.  To do this either add printf()'s to generate trace output at important places (such as the arguments at each function call).  Better yet, learn how to use your debugger.

Comment: One problem:  in `checklocation`, the if statements don't make sense. Mentally trace through the code with `i = j = 0;` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Your `floodfill()` seems to be broken:

when you call it on the location of `P`, the following check

```
if (map[i][j] != '_')
    return;
```

will return immediately without doing anything (as `map[i][j]` is `P` there, not `_`)

Try:

```
if (map[i][j] == '_') {
  map[i][j] = 'P';

  floodfill(map, r, c, i, j+1); //check right
  floodfill(map, r, c, i, j-1); //check left
  floodfill(map, r, c, i+1, j); //check below
  floodfill(map, r, c, i-1, j); //check above
}
```

this will change the current position and only call the surrounding floodfill if needed

Note that this will still skip the initial P, which you can fix by setting `map[i][j]` to `_` right before you call `floodfill()` from `main()`

Also, you seem to be reading too much from the input:

```
map[i][j] = fgetc(ifp);
for (j=0; j<c; j++) {
  map[i][j] = fgetc(ifp);
  ...
```

will read a character for the current `i` and read one for each `j` again.  If you are reading the new-line in the first case, you don't need to store it in `map[i,j]`, especially that doing so will alter the map after the first loop through `j` (which now has the value `c`)

Also, in `checklocation()`, you need to check for the boundary cases before you check the element in `map` (as Gene hinted in the comments), otherwise your boundary checking is worthless.

Comment: But the initial value of map[i][j] when it calls the floodfill function is P, so it will never start the if('_') part. Thats where im stuck

Comment: @user1451642 - true.  Set `map[i][j]` to `'_'` just before you call `floodfill()` from your `main()` function

Comment: Ok I have my read input as
   `for (i=0; i<r; i++){`
           `fscanf(ifp, "%s", map[i]);`


and here is my floodfill call
    `if(map[i][j] == 'P') {`
        `map[i][j] = '_';`
        `floodfill(map, i, j, r, c);`

Comment: @user1451642 - is your problem resolved now, or are you experiencing problems still?

Comment: @user1451642 - in case you are still having problems, here is a working example: [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/oGh6S).  Note that I have changed the file-read calls to stdin-read calls.

Comment: Still have problems with larger inputs. What the problem is is that the P isn't actually being put into the spots where _ is, meaning the checklocation won't ever find a C next to a P

Comment: Ok, this tricked me too: you need to move `r, c` to be the last two parameters of `floodfill` when you are calling it recursively

Comment: I have that now in my current build, and it doesn't seem to help

Comment: Actually, the algorithm was working well after my suggested changes, but the modifications did not propagate back to `main()` as a copy of the whole array was made every time `floodfill()` was called.  I have modified the array to a one-dimentional one, and now you can see the effect of the flooding: http://ideone.com/UblAx

Comment: @Ryan did you figure out this?